# Xcode - Source keeps disappearing and App crashes

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6

I've got a weird issue going on with Xcode and any help is appreciated. I'm running Xcode 4.6.3, building a fairly large project (~40k lines of code).

I open a source file to edit, go about editing the source file and suddenly xcode scrolls to the top of the file and "cuts off" the bottom part of it. I try to scrolldown, nothing happens Code almost looks like an image file that's cut off.

Couple of seconds later, the entire source disappears and I just view a blank page where the source code used to be and then after half a second, Xcode crashes.

If I delete the derived data and the user interface state file in ~/Library/Contents/Developer, things are temporarily back to normal.

This issue still happens frequently enough to be very annoying. Any suggestions?

Thanks, 
Teja

EDIT: Should mention that this is happening only on Mavericks. 4.6.3 + Mountain Lion used to work great.

EDIT2: Here's a video if it helps: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOtCbfRn9A4&feature=youtu.be

Comment: It seems that this also happens on Xcode 5.0.2 on Mavericks. Funny thing, code disappears on iMacs only, MacBooks seem to work fine. All Systems are updated to the latest version of Xcode and Mavericks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted the same question in the Apple forums and they just said Xcode 4.6.* is not supported on Mavericks. I've upgraded to Xcode 5 and haven't had this issue since.

Marking it as accepted until someone else comes up with a better answer.